# Extra elements being added to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was attempting to complete this problem as a newbie, and I'm seeing extra elements within my returned array after my loop.

```
In DNA strings, symbols "A" and "T" are complements of each other, as "C" and "G". 
You have function with one side of the DNA, you need to get the other complementary side.
```

Here is my solution

```js
let dnaComStrand = [];
const DNAStrand = function(dnaStrand) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dnaStrand.length; i++) {
    if (dnaStrand[i] === `A`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `T`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `T`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `A`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `C`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `G`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `G`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `C`;
    }
  }
  //   return dnaComStrand.join(``);
  return dnaComStrand;
};
console.log(DNAStrand(`GCATA`));
```

yet in the console I was seeing

```
Array(5) [ "C", "G", "T", "A", "T" ]
```

which became even more confusing if I tried to call the function again.

```js
let dnaComStrand = [];
const DNAStrand = function(dnaStrand) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dnaStrand.length; i++) {
    if (dnaStrand[i] === `A`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `T`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `T`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `A`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `C`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `G`;
    } else if (dnaStrand[i] === `G`) {
      dnaComStrand[i] = `C`;
    }
  }
  //   return dnaComStrand.join(``);
  return dnaComStrand;
};
console.log(DNAStrand(`GCATA`));
console.log(DNAStrand([`T`, `C`, `G`]));
```

which resulted in

```
Array(5) [ "A", "G", "C", "A", "T" ]
```

Where are these extra elements coming from?

Comment: Since you declared `dnaComStrand` _outside_ the function, then it persists for each function call. If you move it inside the function, you'll be sure you're dealing with an empty array each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const hash = {
  A: 'T',
  T: 'A',
  C: 'G',
  G: 'C',
}

const DNAStrand = dnaStrand => dnaStrand.split('').map(c => hash[c])

// 1
const dnaComStrand1 = DNAStrand(`GCATA`)
console.log(dnaComStrand1)

// 2
const dnaComStrand2 = DNAStrand(dnaComStrand1.join(''))
console.log(dnaComStrand2)
```

Comment: Before I saw your response, this is exactly what I was going to suggest to OP. Much cleaner code.

Answer (score -1):

Reinitialize the array with new set of elements inside the function and before the loop.